# after installing second distro, separate grub2 installs

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

I was googling a lot, but couldn't really find any solution.

I installed Kubuntu 14.04 (sda2) with separate home partition (sda4) in EFI mode.

Then I decided to install a second distro (Ubuntu Studio 14.04).
During installation of Ubuntu Studio (now sda5), the setup recognized Kubuntu and added it to Grub2. So far so good.

```
 $ sudo parted -l
Modell: ATA ST500LT012-1DG14 (scsi)
Festplatte  /dev/sda:  500GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/4096B
Partitionstabelle: gpt

Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   26,8GB  26,2GB  ext4
 4      26,8GB  446GB   419GB   ext4
 5      446GB   496GB   50,3GB  ext4
 3      496GB   500GB   4182MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

The thing is now, that Grub2 seems to be installed with the new OS on sda5. Another copy of grub from the other OS is installed in sda2.

Now if I do update-grub on Kubuntu (on sda2) it changes grub2 on sda2, however, after installing Ubuntu Studio, Grub2 on sda5 seems the one that is used for booting.
Which leaves me with the problem, that grub is not updated properly after an automatic Kernel-update on Kubuntu (sda2), which happens quite often.

**How can I make both distros use the same Grub?**

**Or how do I "turn on" the grub on sda2 again?**
Cause I planned to leave Ubuntu Studio (sda5) as an offline, music only system, so system updates are not necessary for me. Following the concept of "never change a running system".

Comment: You should leave installed in the EFI partition Grub operating system to command the start. 

Then reinstall Grub from another operating system on your root partition /. 

This way you can update without problems both Grub and Grub always installed on the EFI partition, command the start.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Boot Repair](https://launchpad.net/boot-repair)? The software should allow you to synchronize your GRUB menu options across all of your installations.

View the Boot Repair homepage [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/).

Answer (score 0):

Procedure:

a- In Kubuntu:

1. Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run it:

   sudo -i

   apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64

   update-grub

   reboot

b- In Ubuntu Studio:

1. Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run it:

   sudo -i

   grub-install  /dev/sda5

   reboot

c- In Kubuntu:

1. Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run it:

   sudo -i

   update-grub

From now on, the Grub Kubuntu should be handling the menu for both operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But under point 2 did you actually mean grub-install /dev/sda2 indstead of sda5? Cause now, grub from sda5 (iubuntu studio) is handling the boot again.

Comment: In the case that the Ubuntu Grub Studio insist on managing the system, repeats only the point (a) in Kubuntu.